# How to send array as parameter in API Call?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, variables

How to send array as parameter in API Call?

I just want to know how can I pass and array as parameter in Java,

Like:-

```
 "list":[
              {
                 "name":{{$randomFullName}}, 
                 "account":{{$randomAlphaNumeric}},
                 "accountbalance":{{$$randomInt}}
                  
              }

    "Message":  "Dear {{name}}, your {{$accountnumber}} has been credited with Rs.{{($accountbalance)}}.

}

I just want to pass name, account, account-balance in the message body.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be a bit unclear.

If you just want to set the values during runtime, before sending the request, [you need to set the environment and add these as the variables in the postman](https://community.postman.com/t/using-environment-variables-in-a-request-body/34169/2).

Or if you're trying to build the whole list dynamically, then you can write the complete code for that in the request script and simply use that while sending the request. [This](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/documentation/9215231-b9133e48-73c3-4aa4-b189-e038ee4c5e00) can help you with the same.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work that way . You can't use a parameter as an object in a request body . Instead , you should extract the list in your code and then send message accordingly in code only .

Comment: I am trying to use this code in Postman, I have already build a entity class with name, account, account balance, so just try to pass the value

Comment: Your question is unclear ,But what I assume from your question is that you want to use parameters 'name' , 'account', 'accountBalance' as objects and use them in another parameter as we do it in any Coding language which is not possible in Postman .